# Can't figure out the reason for ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception

The following method throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

Method 1 (With exception):

```
public List getData(int n)
{
    List l = new ArrayList(statement.values());
    Iterator i = l.iterator();


    Calculation calculation = null;

    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        calculation = (Calculation)i.next();
        if (!calculation.total.hasScores())
            i.remove();
    }
    Collections.sort(l);
    int size = l.size();

    return l.subList(0,size > n? n : size);
}
```

And when I changed the above method to this:

Method 2 (Without exception):

```
public List getData(int n)
{
    List l = new ArrayList(statement.values());
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    Collections.sort(l);

    Calculation calculation = null;

    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        calculation = (Calculation)i.next();
        if (!calculation.total.hasScores())
            i.remove();
    }

    int size = l.size();

    return l.subList(0,size > n? n : size);
}
```

Then there's no exception! Cannot figure out why?

Exception trace:

```
Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

Complete Class:

```
public class MyData 
{
    private Map <Integer, Calculation> statements = new HashMap<Integer, Calculation>();

    public List getListData()
    {
        List listData = this.getData(5);

        return listData;
    }

    public List getData(int n)
    {
        List l = new ArrayList(statement.values());
        Iterator i = l.iterator();

        Calculation calculation = null;

        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            calculation = (Calculation)i.next();
            if (!calculation.total.hasScores())
                i.remove();
        }

        Collections.sort(l);
        int size = l.size();

        return l.subList(0,size > n? n : size);
    }

}
```

Now when getListData is called exceptions occurs.

Comment: Can you please add exception trace and which line it causes exception

Comment: Updated it with exception trace :)

Comment: Perhaps `i.remove()` never gets called when the array is sorted.

Comment: Please post entire class

Comment: Which one creating exception first or second?

Comment: @Siva Kumar First one!

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - it'll be a lot easier to help you in that case.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - Posted :)

Comment: Just to make sure - you run this in a single-threaded environment? `Iterator.next()` should work perfectly fine if you run the code you posted.

Comment: @BSingh this is not yet a complete minimal example. You are using the missing `Calculation` class, and there is no main method that invokes your method on data that exposes the problem. Best would be to remove `Calculation` from your program, as it doesn't seem to have to do with the problem. Also, your stack trace is not complete.

Comment: @BSingh are you sure it's not the other way around -  the second version throuwing an exception? Because that way it would actually make sense...

Answer (score 3):

Since `sort()` methos jumble up whole collection , you have to call `sort()` method first. After that call `iterator()`.

Comment: `sort()` is only called after the iteration is complete. How is it supposed to trigger a CME, when the iterator is not accessed after sorting?

Comment: Iterators become invalid if you do any modification in that collection unless you do the modification through that iterator itself.
Almost all collections in java are "fail-fast" and it will throw CME if collection get changed.

Comment: I know, but in the first version, which OP claims to throw the exception, the iterator is not used after the call to `sort`. If you wanted to say that the second version suffers from this problem, you should state this. (or ideally, ask OP for clarification instead of answering. after all they are claiming that the second version works)